# Find and replace multiple line string using SSH

Tags: ssh

I'm only a light user of SSH and finding this one a struggle.

I have spammy code littered through my header.php and footer.php files in multiple directories that contains something like the following multiline string:

```
<div style="position:absolute;filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0.001;z-index:10;”>
<a href="http://www.awful.org/" title="awful spammy shoes or whatever online">awful spammy shoes or whatever online</a>
<a href="http://pleasestopspammingme.fr/sneakers/" title="blah blah outlet">blah blah outlet</a>
</div>
```

I'm looking to find and replace or delete the code from the files.

Not 100% sure of what linux tools are available (eg: perl) but happy to give recommendations a try.

Comment: What  does this have to do with the secure shell? You get that it justs creates a secured connection to a terminal, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with an answer with help from a mate.

If there is a standard beginning and a standard ending then sed comes to the rescue.

With an opening string of:

```
<div style="position:absolute;filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0.001;z-index:10;">
```

and a closing string of:

```
</div>
```

Then the following finds and removes the opening string, closing string and anything contained within:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '/<div style="position:absolute;filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0.001;z-index:10;">/,/<\/div>/d' {} \;
```

Tested, works like a charm!