# REGEX to find and replace multiple line string using SSH

Tags: regex, sed

Suppose I have a TXT file:

```
line 1
some text ABC
line 3
line 4
XYZ
```

I want to remove everything between ABC and XYZ, including those 2 strings, so the result should be

```
line 1
some text
```

I use this command

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i '/ABC/,/XYZ/d' {} \;
```

but it deletes also 'some text' part and the result is

```
line 1
```

How to adjust the regex?

It's a modification of this question:
[Find and replace multiple line string using SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629652/find-and-replace-multiple-line-string-using-ssh)
as the answer there deletes whole lines.

Comment: Maybe just run another sed *before* that replaces `ABC` with `\nABC`?

Comment: This does not have anything to do with SSH. SSH is just used to secure the connection; it is not involved in any of the commands. Maybe you're running bash and you try to perform bash scripting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `sed` may work for you:

```bash
sed '/ABC/,/XYZ/{/ABC/!d; s///;}' file

line 1
some text
```

**Breakdown:**

- `/ABC/,/XYZ/`: Operate between patterns `ABC` and `XYZ`
- `{`: Action block start

  - `/ABC/!d;`: If line doesn't have `ABC` then delte it
  - `s///;`:  Substitute search pattern `ABC` with empty string
- `}`: Action block end

Comment: Nice appoach+solution :) `sed '/ABC/,/XYZ/{/ABC/!d; s/ABC.*//;}'` should work as well ^^

Comment: Cool. You put `s///` instead of `s/ABC.*//` though.

Comment: What would happen if another line containing `ABC` were to appear before `XYZ`?

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's/ABC.*XYZ//' input_file
line 1
some text
```

Comment: Might this remove too much?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/ABC/{:a;N;/XYZ/!ba;s/ABC.*XYZ//}' file
```

Gather up lines that begin by containing the string `ABC` and end by containing the string `XYZ`.

Replace `ABC` to the last string that matches `XYZ` by nothing.

N.B. That `.*` is greedy and may remove too much if perchance the last line contains two or more occurrences of the the string `XYZ`, in which case use:

```
sed '/ABC/{:a;N;/XYZ/!ba;s/XYZ/\n/;s/ABC.*\n//}' file
```